# IOS:Convert string to hexadecimal array

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, hex, core-bluetooth

i have string representing data .i need to convert those data to the hex array .By using the hex array data i can pass it to the CRC for writing to the peripheral

My string data is like this

```
          NSString *stringsdata=@"helloworld1234567812345q";
```

i need to convert to hex format array like

```
       {0x0h,0x0e............0x0q}.
```

so by using this array  i can keep the data in the crc and write it to the peripheral data as

```
            Byte comm[24];
            comm[0]=0x01;
            comm[1]=0x30;
            comm[2]=0x62;
            comm[3]=0x00;................
```

have tried with many possible solutions but not luck.can any body help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `0x0h`, `0x0q` are not hexadecimal numbers. You need to be clearer about what you are attempting, and show the code you've tried and say why it doesn't work - then people will have a better chance to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Byte[]` class is an array of characters. I mean you can only set one character at it's index.

If we have

`Byte comm[24];` then `comm[0]=0x01;` is looks like confusing here because it only saves one character.

And the statement will be like `comm[0]='x';`.

Below code will creates `Byte[]` from given string.

```
NSString *stringsdata=@"helloworld1234567812345q";
    CFStringRef cfString = (__bridge CFStringRef)stringsdata;
    char *array = charArrayFromCFStringRef(cfString);
    size_t length= strlen(array);

    Byte comm[24];
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        comm[i] = array[i];
    }
```

Conversion function:

```
char * charArrayFromCFStringRef(CFStringRef stringRef) {
    if (stringRef == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }

    CFIndex length = CFStringGetLength(stringRef);
    CFIndex maxSize = CFStringGetMaximumSizeForEncoding(length, kCFStringEncodingUTF8);

    char *buffer = (char *)malloc(maxSize);
    if (CFStringGetCString(stringRef, buffer, maxSize, kCFStringEncodingUTF8)) {
        return buffer;
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

**OutPut:**

```
Printing description of comm:
(Byte [24]) comm = {
  [0] = 'h'
  [1] = 'e'
  [2] = 'l'
  [3] = 'l'
  [4] = 'o'
  [5] = 'w'
  [6] = 'o'
  [7] = 'r'
  [8] = 'l'
  [9] = 'd'
  [10] = '1'
  [11] = '2'
  [12] = '3'
  [13] = '4'
  [14] = '5'
  [15] = '6'
  [16] = '7'
  [17] = '8'
  [18] = '1'
  [19] = '2'
  [20] = '3'
  [21] = '4'
  [22] = '5'
  [23] = 'q'
}
```

The thing here is if you still convert any character from `Byte[]` then you can only save one character at any index.

Because for above characters it's hex value is more than one character and you can only save one character in `Byte[]`.

I suggest to use `NSArray` to save each character's hex value in `NSString` format.

Comment: your code appears to `malloc` a buffer in `charArrayFromCFStringRef`, return that buffer, copy it to a local array, and then discard the `malloc`'ed buffer without `free`'ing it.

Answer (score 2):

A. The hexadecimal format is simply another representation of the *same* data.

B. You do not convert them into hex array. Every character has a number. For example in ASCII and UTF-8 the `A` has the number 65 (decimal representation). This is 0x41 in hex representation.

'A' (ASCII) == 65 == 0x41.

A hex number has the the digits `0`-`9`, `a`-`f`, wherein `a` has the value of 10, `b` the value of 11 … It is converter into decimal representation by multiplying the upper digit by 16 and adding the lower digit. (0x41: 4 x 16 + 1 = 65.)

Please read and understand this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal

C. To convert a string into its number, you have to know, which code you want to apply. Probably you want to use UTF-8.

```
NSString *text = @"helloworld123123989128739";
NSUInteger length = [text lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
char data[length];
[text getCString:data maxLength:length usingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
// Here we go
```