# Converting NSString to Bytes

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a question regarding the NSString to Bytes conversion.

My question is 
I want to create the NSData from Bytes. Here in the below code everything fine but in place of combinedStr I have to pass int variables.i.e 0101,0102,...

I am getting string variables like @"0101",@"0102"..... in the variable called combinedstring.In case If I convert the combinedstring to int then it is giving the values called 101,102... but I want 0101,0102...... Could anyone please help me to resolve this issue.

```
  NSData *valData = [NSData dataWithBytes:(Byte[]){254,1,200,0.5,combinedstring,0.4,1} length:7];
```

**Please remember combinedstring is a String and variable. In the place of combinedstring we can only pass int values.**

Please let me know if my question is not clear

Comment: Have a look on this answer too - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27700431/iosconvert-string-to-hexadecimal-array/27700913#27700913

Answer (score 2):

You can convert an instance of `NSString` to an instance of `NSData` with 
`-dataUsingEncoding:allowLossyConversion:` or to a C array with `-getCString:maxLength:encoding:(NSStringEncoding)encoding`.

In both cases you have a pointer to an object resp. to a `char[]`. Putting that pointer into the `Byte` array, will convert the pointer and copy its value, but not the referenced data.

Additionally: In your example you try to save `0.4` (zero – period – four) and `0.5` (zero – period – 5) into a `Byte[]`. This will not do the job, you probably expect. It will convert the value to a value of type `Byte` (an integer type!) and store that value. Integer values greater than 255 will be converted, too.

Therefore you have to use a mutable data object and concat the binary representation of the different types individually.

An example:

```
NSData *stringData = [combinedString dataUsingEncoding:… allowLossyConversion:NO];
if (stringData == nil)
{
   // error handling
}


NSMutableData *data = [NMutableData new];
Byte *byteArray;
float *floatArray;

// Adding byte data
byteArray = (Byte[]){254,1,200};
[data appendBytes:byteArray length:3*sizeof(Byte)]; // Adds 254, 1, 200

// Adding floating point data – Hopefully the receiver has the same floating point format.
floatArray = (float[]){0.5};
[data appendBytes:floatArray length:1*sizeof(float)]; // Adds 4! bytes representing the float value

// Adding string data – Hopefully the receiver uses the same string encoding
[data appendData:stringData]; // Adds the bytes for the string in the above encoding.
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Please give me some time to test it.

Comment: I typed it in Safari, so likely there some typos. You should understand how pointers, arrays and binary data works in C. This is only an example.